# SQLAlchemy: Deleting child objects doesn't update parent

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) 1.2.11, I have two ORM models defined like so (simplified):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    ForeignKey,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    # columns
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # relationships
    children = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    # columns
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = (Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete='cascade'))

    # relationships
    parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')
```

I'm creating both objects, adding to the session, and flushing:

```
parent = Parent()
child = Child()
parent.children.append(child)

session.add(child)
session.flush()
```

Finally, I'm deleting the child object:

```
session.delete(child)
session.flush()
```

All relevant SQL statements are flushed; both the initial inserts, as well as the subsequent delete.

My expectation would be, since this session is 'tracked', that `len(parent.children)` would `== 0`. However, the child object is still attached.

I've toyed with the `cascade` options on both sides of the relationship, but neither updates the session on a flush operation. Only `session.commit()` seems to stick, by forcing the next set of SQL operations to occur within *another* transaction block, causing the side-effect of lazy-loading when invoking the `parent.children` path and firing off 'refreshed' SQL to the DB.

My question is - is it possible to have SQLAlchemy remove deleted objects from `parent.children` that it knows are deleted in a flush operation *without* committing it?

Comment: `session.refresh(parent)` worked for me